# Shared config file for various VSTS roles

Tags: azure-devops

I know how to make a shared config file for traditional projects and adding them to each project with the following tag:
 `<appSettings file="../other_project/foo.config">`.

How do I share application settings in VSTS, ensuring every role can access the shared config settings? I assume you can't directly reference other projects' config files using relative path names, like in my example above.

I would like to centralize my configuration and make my config transform file relatively short, as there are a lot of projects.

Comment: What are you using for source control? Are you keeping everything in a single team project, or do you have multiple team projects?

Comment: @DanielMann We're keeping everything in one shared VSTS git repo.

Comment: If everything is in the same repo, then why can't you do references as relative paths?

Comment: @DanielMann Will those work if I'm deploying my different projects as roles on different machines?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume you can't directly reference other projects' config files
>   using relative path names, like in my example above.

You can manage the config file into **solution directory** or **the root of your git repo**.

Then you can add (Add -> Existing Item) the config file for each project separately.

And keep the config file as artifacts, so even when deploying different projects into different machines, the config file will always accessible.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So I could have a App.dev.config and App.prod.config at the root level. I would use appSettings file="..." to point to it, and some form of config transforms to change the filename depending on whether I want dev or prod. What's the best way to perform that transform?

Comment: Where do you want to deploy your app? Such as for Azure App Service Deploy task, you can combine variables with transformation (as the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701401/populate-web-config-with-build-variables).

Comment: I actually went ahead and did that, but now it doesn't seem to be transforming: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124270/cant-transform-xml-when-deploying-to-vsts?noredirect=1#comment87272777_50124270

Comment: As starain asked in that post, can you share an example code in one drive and the build/release definition configuration?