# Can't transform XML when deploying to VSTS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, app-config, web-config-transform

For a VSTS worker role, I'm trying to build configuration transforms so I can change settings based on the environment.

I created two files in my solution directory, App.dev.config and App.prod.config, which I have linked to a test project. I then used [this tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform#overview) to apply config  transforms and generate the files App.Debug.config and App.Release.config.

In my worker role's regular old app.config, I specify that app settings normally come from the App.dev.config file, so it can either remain in place or get overwritten with a tranform.
`<appSettings file="App.dev.config">`.

In my App.Release.config file, I have the following transform to point my appSettings to read from my production definition: `<appSettings file="App.prod.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(file)">`

My machinations work fine when I switch between debug and release configurations on my local machine. I successfully see environment variables printed out depending on whether I select "release" or "debug." However, when I deploy to VSTS and specify "release" in my BuildConfiguration variable, the log files *say* they're doing the transformation, but if I look at the config file on the remote machine no such transformation has occurred.

[Here are my log files.](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkKP2QDfi8r_bBP6_Q5T438l0P8)

As you can see, they show that some kind of transformation succeeded:

> 2018-05-01T19:58:08.9166019Z App_config_AfterCompile:
>   2018-05-01T19:58:08.9166379Z   Transforming Source File: App.config
>   2018-05-01T19:58:08.9311923Z     Applying Transform File: App.Release.config
>   2018-05-01T19:58:08.9767602Z     Output File: obj\Release\DeviceCloud.Application.ReportWorker.exe.config
>   2018-05-01T19:58:09.0006922Z   Transformation succeeded

So, I'm not sure why my DeviceCloud.Application.ReportWorker.exe.config file doesn't have the transformations applied.

Comment: Which file you checked? What's the file path?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT The supposedly transformed config file is on the remote machine under E:\AppRoot\DeviceCloud.Application.ReportWorker.exe.config. It still points to App.dev.config under the file attribute.

Comment: Can you please add the build task configuration screen shot to your question?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the simple projects? If so, you can share the sample projects on the OneDrive.